# Google Docs Scripting - Permissions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Simple question: How does one allow people with *Commenting Privileges* to use a custom menu or view a sidebar? Is this even possible, or can only editors use custom scripts? The idea is that I want people to authorize a script which will allow them to add questions to the document, but I do not want them to be able to directly edit the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not possible. only editors can run scripts in a spreadsheet.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal are a bot? this clearly answers exactly what is being asked.